# Error: Importing notebooks requires Jupyter nbconvert to be installed. Julia

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I am trying to export a Julia Jupyter Notebook to pdf

I installed last version of Julia and VS Code (and the Julia and jupyter extension on VS Code)

I can do fine in jupyter notebooks, the code runs and it's saved on `.ipynb` format.

So this is what i've done:

In the cmd I just put

```
py -m pip install jupyter

py -m pip install nbconvert
```

But whenever I try to export the notebook from VS Code I get this error:

```
Error 2021-10-19 19:25:11: Export failed [Error: Importing notebooks requires Jupyter nbconvert to be installed.
    at u.getExportInterpreter (c:\Users\jparedesm\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.9.1101343141\out\client\extension.js:37:319922)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async b.export (c:\Users\jparedesm\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.9.1101343141\out\client\extension.js:52:919260)
    at async g.export (c:\Users\jparedesm\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.9.1101343141\out\client\extension.js:37:290037)
    at async l._executeContributedCommand (c:\Users\jparedesm\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:111644)]
Error 2021-10-19 19:25:11: If you have not installed xelatex (TeX) you will need to do so before you can export to PDF, for further instructions go to https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-tex. 
To avoid installing xelatex (TeX) you might want to try exporting to HTML and using your browsers "Print to PDF" feature.
```

I do have MikTex installed.

So I don't know what is going on.

Please, let me know how to export a jupyter notebook.

---

This is what the notebook looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem than yours. The only difference, as I can guess, is that I'm using Mac and have TeXShop instead of MikTex. I have compiled .tex files using xelatex, so I think we both need to tell Visual Studio Code where is the xelatex file. I did a bit of research on the Internet and find suggestions to install the LaTex Workshop extension on VSC. It didn't solve the problem for me, but it'd work for you. I hope so. Let me know in that case.

Best,

Comment: it's a bit strange, cause in Jupiter (anaconda) I can export to pdf from a macbook, using mactex, but I will search it up that extension, thanks!!